# Word Press: How to add custom validation to Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use this plug in: Advanced Custom Fields and add my own validation for specific fields.

I tried to follow this post:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-validate_value/

But what file do I change in my word press folder to allow it to work?

I'm trying to validate a Pin # that matches 1234.

I have recently tried to put it in the acf plugin folder for validation.php.

I tried it in here:

[In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txONc.png)

```
function acf_validate_value( $value, $field, $input ) {

    // vars
    $valid   = true;
    $message = sprintf( __( '%s value is required', 'acf' ), $field['label'] );

    // valid
    if ( $field['required'] ) {

        // valid is set to false if the value is empty, but allow 0 as a valid value
        if ( empty( $value ) && ! is_numeric( $value ) ) {

            $valid = false;

        }
    }

    /**
    *  Filters whether the value is valid.
    *
    *  @date    28/09/13
    *  @since   5.0.0
    *
    *  @param   bool $valid The valid status. Return a string to display a custom error message.
    *  @param   mixed $value The value.
    *  @param   array $field The field array.
    *  @param   string $input The input element's name attribute.
    */
    $valid = apply_filters( "acf/validate_value/type={$field['type']}", $valid, $value, $field, $input );
    $valid = apply_filters( "acf/validate_value/name={$field['_name']}", $valid, $value, $field, $input );
    $valid = apply_filters( "acf/validate_value/key={$field['key']}", $valid, $value, $field, $input );
    $valid = apply_filters( 'acf/validate_value', $valid, $value, $field, $input );
    $valid = add_filter('acf/validate_value/name=registration_pin', 'my_acf_validate_value', 10, 4);

    // allow $valid to be a custom error message
    if ( ! empty( $valid ) && is_string( $valid ) ) {

        $message = $valid;
        $valid   = false;

    }

    if ( ! $valid ) {

        acf_add_validation_error( $input, $message );
        return false;

    }

    // return
    return true;

}

function my_acf_validation_registation_pin($valid, $value, $field, $input_name ){
    // Bail early if value is already invalid.
    if( $valid !== true ) {
        return $valid;
    }

    console.log('validate registration pin: test ->' + new Date());
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, what kind of acf-field and value are you trying to validate, and what data are you validating the value against? Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: It's a filter, so ```functions.php``` in your theme should be fine as it gets loaded quite late (usually after the plugins). Have a look at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-theme-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first.

Comment: This filter can used in functions.php and with a function to handle the validation.

Comment: @joshmoto: updated with things I've tried since posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah your code wont work. The `add_filter` will be hit too late.

If you are simply trying to get an acf field to validate the submitted value against a defined set value.

Best way to do this is to add this to your `functions.php`, see comments in my code below...

```php
<?php

// add validate value filter for all acf fields with the field name `registration_pin`
// you can use `acf/validate_value/key=` to target a specific acf field by key if you have multiple fields with the same name `registration_pin` in different field groups
add_filter('acf/validate_value/name=registration_pin', 'acf_validate_reg_pin', 10, 4);

// function used by the above `add_filter`
function acf_validate_reg_pin($valid, $value, $field, $input_name) {

    // define our registration pin to validate submitted value against
    $reg_pin = '1234';

    // if submitted value is empty or false
    // remove this condition if you want the form to still validate if the field value is empty/false
    if(!$value) {

        // field returns invalid and show this error message
        return __('Please enter registration pin.');

    }

    // if submitted value is a string and is not equal to our defined registration pin
    if(is_string($value) && $value !== $reg_pin) {

        // field returns invalid and show this error message
        return __('Incorrect registration pin.');

    }

    // return field as valid, if none of the above conditions are true
    return $valid;

}
```

This might make it a bit clearer for you about how to handle validation on specific acf fields. You should use this `add_filter` in your `functions.php` so the filter is hit.

You can use `require_once(__DIR__ . '/folder/example.php');` in your `functions.php`, if you want to keep things tidy in your functions. You can load php files, lib classes, etc... everything required here runs first in the wordpress admin and your theme.